# Can I use pretty much any identifier if I use << operator with strings?

Tags: ruby, string, heredoc

Example:

```
puts <<BLOCK
...
BLOCK
```

with BLOCK being any other identifier that doesn't clash with a keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; you can--any legal symbol or quoted string may be used.

For example, if you want to throw a bang in it, you have to use the quoted form:

```
pry(main)> s = <<"foo!bar"
pry(main)* yo
pry(main)* foo!bar
=> "yo\n"
pry(main)> puts s
yo
```

If it's a symbol then you don't need to quote it.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't understand whether it's just a simple token identifier.

Comment: @stanigator Well, it's not a token in the sense of "it can be any string", it can't, say, have an operator like "-" in it, unless the first instance is quoted. Editing to show example.